# ¿Como imprimir un array con return en php?

Tags: php, array

Quiero imprimir un array, pero con **`return`** no me deja , si uso **`echo`** si funciona:

```
<?php
function imprimirArrays($a){

$sizeA=sizeof($a);
$respuesta=array();

for ($i=0; $i <$sizeA; $i++) { 

  $respuesta[]=$a[$i] ;
}

return $respuesta;

}
```

El HTML

```
<?php
include_once"arrays1.php";
?>
<!doctype hmtl>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    
 $a=array(3,5,4,890);
 $respuesta=imprimirArrays($a);
 echo $respuesta;/*linea 11 donde esta el error*/
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Al usar el return me sale el  siguiente error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica\imprimiendo-arrays.php on line 11  Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para imprimir un array debes usar la funcion var_dump($array) o print_r($array), en tu funcion `imprimirArrays` en vez de la asignacion `$respuesta[]=$a[$i] ;` debes de hacer un `echo $a[$i]` y retornar un boolean en todo caso. [https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php]. saludos

Answer (score 2):

Aclaremos unos puntos:

- El error que muestras no es por el uso de return, es por qué tratas de imprimir una estructura de datos compleja con echo que solo te va a servir para imprimir valores primitivos como:

  - String
  - Number
  - Booleans
- El uso de return es para que la función devuelva algún resultado procesado
- Si requieres imprimir una estructura de datos como un array entonces debes hacer alguna de estas opciones:

  - Has uso de print_r o var_dump
  - Itera con un ciclo foreach a tu array y ahora sí por dentro de este podrías imprimir cada elemento del array con echo

Para el caso de ocupar echo hacemos lo siguiente:

```
foreach($respuesta as $numero)
{
    echo $numero."<br />;
}
```

Iteramos cada posición del array y el valor recuperado por cada vuelta lo almacenamos en la variable $numero la cual ahora sí por dentro del ciclo podemos imprimir con echo

**Edición**

Si por otro lado tienes una matriz de datos, N cantidad de arrays dentro de otro array principal, hacer lo anterior nos daría la misma notificación que ya obtienes (atendiendo a quien me hizo la observación).

Entonces lo que procede es generar otro ciclo foreach dentro del principal para que podamos iterar los elementos de los arrays internos.

**Ejemplo**

```
$datosNivelUno = array(
                    array(1, 2, 4, 5),
                    array(6, 7, 9, 10)
                );

foreach($datosNivelUno as $nivelPrincipal)
{
    foreach($nivelPrincipal as $numeros)
    {
        echo $numeros.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
1
2
4
5
6
7
9
10
```

Comment: Solo por aclararlo, (porque en tu respuesta asumes que cada elemento en el ciclo se puede imprimir con echo, y sin embargo, si fueran arrays u objetos estaríamos en el mismo problema) que habría que iterar por cada elemento si este no fuera imprimible con echo.